# Excel - Total hours between two times (not in h:mm format)

Tags: excel, time

I need to calculate how many hours between two times but not in h:mm format.

For example:

Start time: 11:30 AM

End Time: 5:00 PM

Total Hours = 5.5

The [h]:mm format comes up to 5:30 because it is on a base of 60. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that will help. Take the difference between the two times and multiply it by 24. Then **right click** the cell and go to **Format Cells** and then format it as a **Number**

[image]